# Can clang format add braces to single line if statements etc

Tags: c++, clang, clang-format

Is there an option for clang-format to add braces to all if()/do/while statements etc?

eg

```
if( i == 42 )
   std::cout << "You found the meaning of life\n";
else
   std::cout << "Wrong!\n";
```

to

```
if( i == 42 )
{
   std::cout << "You found the meaning of life\n";
}
else
{
   std::cout << "Wrong!\n";
}
```

Using

```
$ clang-format --version
clang-format version 3.6.0
```

Comment: I did not find any option for this in a quick scan of the [Clang-Format Style Options.](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html)

Comment: @BaummitAugen I could not either - but the description of what some of the options do is very vague IMHO

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57318252/752843) for a way of searching for common occurrences of single-lines without braces.

Comment: You just could't make this up. They format everything...... except this

Answer (score 46, accepted):

clang-tidy can make syntactic changes to your code using FIXITS

```
clang-tidy YOUR_FILE.cpp -fix -checks="readability-braces-around-statements" -- COMPILE_OPTIONS
```

Updated:

clang-tidy is a bit of a heavyweight tool for this as it needs compile options to parse the file, sadly clang-format (as of v3.9) won't add braces.

`COMPILE_OPTIONS` would be the include paths etc that you use to compile the file with, ie `-std=c++14 -stdlib=libc++ -O2 -I.`

If you have a `compile_options.json` file from CMake then you can pass the path of the directory it is contained in to clang-tidy and it will look up the appropriate compile options for the file:

```
clang-tidy YOUR_FILE.cpp -fix -checks="readability-braces-around-statements" -p COMPILE_OPTIONS_DIR
```

Comment: Is it possible to run this without making a compilation database? Say I purely only wanted to run the readability check, without looking for compile errors. I ask because I want to edit individual files independent of the entire project. When I try to do this I get `Error while trying to load a compilation database` and `Running without flags.` Which I think is to say that it ignores the readability check, since it does not add the braces as I'd wished.

Comment: To give a concrete example, say my file has `#include "../header.h"` but I am editing the file in a directory with no `header.h` in the parent directory. Is it possible to still use clang-tidy in this scenario?

Comment: I've updated my answer with extra info as it won't neatly fit in a comment.

Comment: I'm not sure I can think of compiler flags that would get your particular example, with a file referenced by a relative include, working.

Comment: clang-tidy is just really a front-end for the static analyzer. It really needs to be part of your build process.

Comment: @jbcoe Checking in, as of version clang-format 7.0, is it still impossible for it to add braces?

Comment: @TylerShellberg Have you found anything out about this?

Answer (score 26):

Starting clang-format-15 (currently trunk), the answer is yes - using the new `InsertBraces` option, which landed just today:
https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/commit/77e60bc42c48e16d646488d43210b1630cd4db49
https://reviews.llvm.org/D120217

From the clang-format [documentation](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html):

> InsertBraces (Boolean) clang-format 15
>
> Insert braces after control statements (if, else, for, do, and while) in C++ unless the control statements are inside macro definitions or the braces would enclose preprocessor directives.
>
> Warning:
>
> Setting this option to true could lead to incorrect code formatting due to clang-format’s lack of complete semantic information. As such, extra care should be taken to review code changes made by this option.

```
false:                                    true:

if (isa<FunctionDecl>(D))        vs.      if (isa<FunctionDecl>(D)) {
  handleFunctionDecl(D);                    handleFunctionDecl(D);
else if (isa<VarDecl>(D))                 } else if (isa<VarDecl>(D)) {
  handleVarDecl(D);                         handleVarDecl(D);
else                                      } else {
  return;                                   return;
                                          }

while (i--)                      vs.      while (i--) {
  for (auto *A : D.attrs())                 for (auto *A : D.attrs()) {
    handleAttr(A);                            handleAttr(A);
                                            }
                                          }

do                               vs.      do {
  --i;                                      --i;
while (i);                                } while (i);
```

Comment: Interesting - I think I'll pull and build it to try it out - I wonder if it handles `#defines` better than clang-tidy does. clang-tidy always makes a mess of 
`if(x==y)
#ifdef OS1
   z=103
#else
   z=-23
#endif`
Only 8 years after I asked ;-)

Comment: @AdrianCornish shouldn't this be the accepted answer?